# Android: How to render html in webview without displaying webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to render html using a Webview, but I don't want to show the content.  To do this I create a Webview programatically and load the HTML.  It is almost working.  The issue is I don't appear to be able to set the dimensions of the Webview, so that the HTML is rendered at the size I would like.  I am using a WebviewClient to take a snapshot of the WebviewContent and convert it to a Bitmap.

The following code is just for testing and not my final intent.  I don't want to show the content at all, but this tests the functionality, an Image is populated when the user hits the print button.  I'd like the image to be a width of 380 (the height can as high as is necessary).  The image is very small ( 87 x 144 ).

I have 2 issues with the following code:

1. The first time it runs, the snapshot always throws an exception indicating the Bitmap dimensions must be > 0
2. On the second attempt (and subsequent attempts) the resulting Bitmap is not the desired dimensions.  And of course scaling just makes it much worse.

   package com.b2ps.htmlrender;

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.Canvas;
   import android.graphics.Paint;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.webkit.WebView;
   import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.util.Log;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;

   /**

   - MainActivity
   - 

   */
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
    private static final String TAG = "USDK";

    private ImageView ImagePreview = null;
    private WebView mReceiptView = null;
    private WebViewClient mWebviewClient = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();

        Button printBtn = ( Button )findViewById( R.id.btnPrint );
        printBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onPrintClicked();
            }
        });

        ImagePreview = ( ImageView )findViewById( R.id.imgPreview );
    }


    private void onPrintClicked() {
        print();
    }

    private void print() {
        mReceiptView = new WebView( this );
        mWebviewClient = new SnapshotWebviewClient( this );
        mReceiptView.setWebViewClient( mWebviewClient );
        mReceiptView.setMinimumWidth( 380 );
        mReceiptView.setMinimumHeight( 720 );

        String receiptHtml = getHtml();
        mReceiptView.loadData( receiptHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8" );

    }

    protected String getHtml() {
        StringBuilder htmlStr = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( this.getAssets().open("Receipt2.html" ) ) );

            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine;
            while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //process line
                htmlStr.append( mLine );
                htmlStr.append( "\n" );
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
            Log.e( TAG, "IO exception", e);
        }
        finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                    Log.e( TAG, "error closing stream", e );
                }
            }
        }
        return htmlStr.toString();
    }



    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // #region SnapshotWebviewClient

    /**
     * SnapshotWeviewClient
     */
    private static class SnapshotWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {

        private static final String TAG = "USDK";

        private MainActivity mMainActivity;

        public SnapshotWebviewClient( MainActivity activity ) {
            mMainActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // FYI anyone wanting to do this right, use webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height then
            // set the Frame of the webview. Works perfect!

            Log.i( TAG, "SnapshotWebviewClient.onPageFinished" );
            super.onPageFinished( view, url );

            try
            {
                // Thread.sleep( 25 );

                // Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap( view.MeasuredWidth, view.ContentHeight, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888 );
                // Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bitmap );
                // Paint paint = new Paint();
                // int iHeight = bitmap.Height;
                // canvas.DrawBitmap( bitmap, 0, iHeight, paint );
                // view.Draw( canvas );

                Bitmap bitmap = screenshot( view );
                // bitmap = scaleToReceipt( bitmap, 380 );
                Log.i( TAG, String.format( "Bitmap size: w(%d), h(%d)", bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight() ) );
                mMainActivity.ImagePreview.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

                // save bitmap to file
                java.io.File externalPath = view.getContext().getExternalFilesDir( null );
                java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File( externalPath, "Receipt.png" );
                java.io.FileOutputStream stream = new java.io.FileOutputStream( filePath );
                bitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream );
                stream.close();
                Log.i( TAG, "WebViewClient.PrintToBitmap" );
            }
            catch ( Exception printErr )
            {
                Log.e( TAG, "PrintWebView: "+printErr.toString(), printErr );
            }
        }


        private Bitmap screenshot(android.webkit.WebView webView )
        {
            webView.measure( View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( 0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ),
                    android.view.View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( 0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ) );
            Log.i( TAG, String.format( "webView dimensions1: w(%d), h(%d)", webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight() ) );
            webView.layout( 0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight() );
            Log.i( TAG, String.format( "webView dimensions2: w(%d), h(%d)", webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight() ) );
            webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled( true );
            webView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
            Log.i( TAG, String.format( "HtmlBmp: w(%d), h(%d)", bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight() ) );

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bitmap );
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            int iHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap, 0, iHeight, paint );
            webView.draw( canvas );
            return bitmap;
        }

        private Bitmap scaleToReceipt( Bitmap bmp, int printWidth )
        {
            double scale = (( double )(printWidth - 1) / ( double )bmp.getWidth());
            int w = ( int )(bmp.getWidth() * scale);
            int h = ( int )(bmp.getHeight() * scale);
            Log.i( TAG, String.format( "Scale Bmp: W(%d), H(%d)", w, h ) );
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bmp, w, h, true );
        }

    }

    // #endregion SnapshowWebviewClient
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

   }

this is the layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPrint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Print" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So I solved one of my problems.  I can now get a bitmap that is scaled to the correct size.

Instead of:

mReceiptView.setMinimumWidth( 380 );
mReceiptView.setMinimumHeight( 720 );

use:

mReceiptView.layout( 0, 0, 380, 720 );

I will set the answer when the other problem is solve.  I still get a bitmap size of 0 x 0 on the first iteration of this call.  And internmittenly.  It happens less when I am debugging and set a breakpoint.  So it appears there is some timeing issue.  But I am doing everything on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve issue (1), call WebView.Layout(...) instead of setting width and height.

To resolve issue (2), the WebView must be created in an Activities onCreate(...) method.

See below:

```
/**
 * MainActivity
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "USDK";

    private ImageView ImagePreview = null;
    private WebView mReceiptView = null;
    private WebViewClient mWebviewClient = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();

        Button printBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrint);
        printBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onPrintClicked();
            }
        });

        ImagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);

        mReceiptView = new WebView( this.getApplicationContext() );
        mWebViewClientClient = new ReceiptWebViewClient();

        mReceiptView.layout( 0, 0, 380, 720 );
        mReceiptView.setWebViewClient( mWebViewClientClient );
        mReceiptView.loadData("<html></html>", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8" );

    }


    private void onPrintClicked() {
        print();
    }

    private void print() {
        String receiptHtml = getHtml();
        mReceiptView.loadData(receiptHtml, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");

    }

    protected String getHtml() {
        StringBuilder htmlStr = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("Receipt2.html")));

            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine;
            while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //process line
                htmlStr.append(mLine);
                htmlStr.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
            Log.e(TAG, "IO exception", e);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                    Log.e(TAG, "error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return htmlStr.toString();
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // #region SnapshotWebviewClient

    /**
     * SnapshotWeviewClient
     */
    private static class SnapshotWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {

        private static final String TAG = "USDK";

        private MainActivity mMainActivity;

        public SnapshotWebviewClient(MainActivity activity) {
            mMainActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // FYI anyone wanting to do this right, use webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height then
            // set the Frame of the webview. Works perfect!

            Log.i(TAG, "SnapshotWebviewClient.onPageFinished");
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            if ( url.compareTo( "data:text/html; charset=utf-8,<html></html>" ) == 0 )
                return;

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = screenshot(view);
                // bitmap = scaleToReceipt( bitmap, 380 );
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Bitmap size: w(%d), h(%d)", bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()));
                mMainActivity.ImagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                // save bitmap to file
                java.io.File externalPath = view.getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
                java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(externalPath, "Receipt.png");
                java.io.FileOutputStream stream = new java.io.FileOutputStream(filePath);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                stream.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "WebViewClient.PrintToBitmap");
            } catch (Exception printErr) {
                Log.e(TAG, "PrintWebView: " + printErr.toString(), printErr);
            }
        }


        private Bitmap screenshot(android.webkit.WebView webView) {
            webView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    android.view.View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("webView dimensions1: w(%d), h(%d)", webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight()));
            webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight());
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("webView dimensions2: w(%d), h(%d)", webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight()));
            webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("HtmlBmp: w(%d), h(%d)", bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()));

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            int iHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, iHeight, paint);
            webView.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        }

        private Bitmap scaleToReceipt(Bitmap bmp, int printWidth) {
            double scale = ((double) (printWidth - 1) / (double) bmp.getWidth());
            int w = (int) (bmp.getWidth() * scale);
            int h = (int) (bmp.getHeight() * scale);
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Scale Bmp: W(%d), H(%d)", w, h));
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, w, h, true);
        }

    }

    // #endregion SnapshowWebviewClient
    //-----------------------------

}
```